# Use select option change value inside click function

Tags: javascript

I need to display the value of the selected item as alert when the user clicks on the #btnValue button.

```
jQuery(function() {
    var catg_str = "";

    $('#btnValue').click(function() {
        alert(catg_str);
    }

    $( "#catg_list" ).change(function () {
        $("#catg_list option:selected").each(function() {
            catg_str += $( this ).text();
        });
    });
});
```

I need to display the value inside `catg_str` as alert when user clicks the `#btnValue` button. The code above works but the value displays as `"undefined"`. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Just alert the `.val()` of the `select` element -- it will be the `value` attribute of the selected option:

```
alert($("catg_list").val());
```